# TraceRt command in the .NET CF Application

Tags: .net, windows, mobile, network-programming

I am trying to connect my Mobile device (WM 6.0 PE) through a GPRS Connectivity. I want to check the tracert of a server to which this device is connected as to check whether the connection is stable or not using Tracert. Is there anyway i can use the Tracert or Ping command to check the Latency of my connection in a windows mobile application.

Thanks in advance
Biju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a oldshool application called vxUtil you could used, it can be found at http://www.cam.com/vxutil_pers.html